# How does this lithium battery charger 3S work?

Tags: charger, lithium

I am trying to figure out how this [lithium battery charger](https://www.communica.co.za/products/hkd-3s-lith-batt-charge-prot-40a?utm_source=www.communica.co.za&variant=46238503403820&sfdr_ptcid=31591_617_699455227&sfdr_hash=9ebedb66920230f1897876f55650726a&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwte-vBhBFEiwAQSv_xZ7ZTmKnpnPZ-oiSu2Sb25xXas1YSdGkzGFzxgbgRNXWwSj-HCga5RoCLRoQAvD_BwE) works.

[image]

How exactly do those discharge/bleeding resistors work? Are they only "activated" when no power is present so that each battery can equalize its voltage via those resistors? Are they disconnected from the circuit when a load is connected?

I don't see an MCU on the PCB, so what is monitoring the three voltages in order to make it safe?

What are those 6-pin ICs used for?

Does anyone know where I can find a schematic for the PCB?

Edit 1:
So the datasheet for the HY2213 says it a "1 Cell Li-ion/Polymer Battery Charge Balance IC". This component is used in the above device (The 6 pin ICs close to the bleed resistors). The other 6 pin IC is a DW01-P or One Cell Lithium-ion/Polymer Battery Protection IC.

[HY2213](https://files.waveshare.com/upload/1/18/DS-HY2213_EN.pdf)

Comment: That looks like the sort of BMS sold on the likes of Amazon. It's not a charger.

Comment: This is not a charger. It's a BMS. Don't try to use it as a charger.

Comment: The six SOT23-6 you speak is likely a buck/boost DC-DC converter. It's difficult to say without its part numbers but considering that there's no other component like that one, I'm fairly certain that's what it is.

Comment: @Finbarr so then what is the difference between a bms and charger? Also is the TP4056 a type of charger I could use for this bms application?

Comment: No, a TP4056 is designed to charge a single Li ion cell, not three in series. You would need three of them together with three isolated power supplies.

Comment: why three isolated power supplies? Can't I connect the positive to the last battery's positive and the negative to the first battery's negative? I assume that what the BMS is there for, is to make sure the 3 batteries do not explode while charging.

Comment: @StarCat please see edit 1. The datasheet for of the components says its a charging IC. Is this therefore not safe to use as a charger?

Comment: @JoeyB which chip is the charger (to be sure) and, please link the data sheet. The HY2213 is not a charger btw. There's a difference between a charger and a charge balancer.

Comment: @Andyaka please see links above. Okay but there are using there are no other ICs for the UPS HAT, just those two, so are you saying this PCB (UPS HAT) is not designed correctly?

Comment: I'm saying that if it describes itself as a charger, I don't see any charger chips in the design @JoeyB

Comment: @Andyaka Okay now I am even more confused about this work. Do you have any resources to show the correct way of doing this? It is clear these PCBs I have shown are not designed properly, especially from your comment "I don't see any charger chips ..." Because the UPS HAT clearly shows you just plug in a 8.4V DC input and everything else is taken care of....

Comment: Does the documentation associated with the PCBs explicitly say they perform battery charging? I didn't see anything for the hat thing @JoeyB ||| 8.4 volts DC is just the float charge voltage; you shouldn't apply that to a discharged battery because that's where the charger comes in and limits the current.

Comment: @Andyaka unless the charger IC is in the charger itself that plugs into the UPS HAT... The PCBs do not say they perform battery charging explicitly so I will check if the charging IC is in the actual charger that it came with.

Comment: The schematic of the UPS Hat that you added later (Edit 1) does not match the picture of the BMS board that was in the initial question. *Which one of these is this question about?*

Comment: The initial question is about a completely different circuit than the schematic you added later. There is no charging IC on the first picture. The Waveshare UPS is not the same as, nor comparable to, the BMS you show in the initial post, so the information you added is just confusing. Part of their circuitry may have the same function, but the Waveshare UPS has additional functionality that is not present on the BMS.

Comment: It was confusing to me anyway. FYI, there is a description and a schematic of the 25 A version of this BMS that can be found [here](https://320volt.com/en/bms-3s-25a-circuit-diagram-modified/). It's very similar to the 40A version.

Comment: @StarCat I have edited the post and removed stuff relating to the WAVESHARE UPS, let me know if it is okay now? Secondly, thank you for the link in your post, perhaps you can add it as an answer so people don't have to dig through the comments. I will also delete my comments relating to the WAVESHARE UPS.

Comment: @Andyaka I just opened the charger that is supplied with WAVESHARE UPS and they are using a LM358  as the main "charging" IC.... :-O

Answer (score 2):

First, that is not a "lithium battery charger". That is a **li-ion** battery **management system**".

A charger regulates current and voltage. This circuit doesn't. It can only turn the battery off. In addition to this protector BMS, you also need a separate device: an actual charger.

> How exactly do those discharge/bleeding resistors work?

They are turned on when the cell voltage exceeds a threshold.

> Are they only "activated" when no power is present so that each battery can equalize its voltage via those resistors?

No. They work regardless and independently.

> Are they disconnected from the circuit when a load is connected?

No. They work regardless and independently.

> I don't see an MCU on the PCB, so what is monitoring the three voltages in order to make it safe?

That is a "hat": it's added to a single-board computer (e.g., Raspberry Pi) that does the control. (Note connector RP11 at the bottom right of the schematic diagram.) By the way, that is extremely unreliable because you have no idea when that computer becomes unavailable. Do not do that because it's very dangerous. Instead, buy a standalone protector BMS.

> What are those 6-pin ICs used for?

They are not ICs, they are MOSFETs (transistors). They are power switches to turn off the battery current. There are two in parallel to increase the current handling. There are two in anti-series (back to back) to control the charging current and the discharging current independently. The third pair (on the right) looks like an ideal diode.

Answer (score 0):

A typical BMS will carry out several functions.

It will disconnect the battery if any individual cell voltage gets to high.

It will disconnect the battery if any individual cell voltage gets to low.

It will try to equalize the charge state of all the cells. This is what the resistors are for. As the battery approaches full charge one or more of the cells will have a higher voltage across it than the others indicating a higher state of charge. The BMS will detect the higher voltage and connect one of those resistors across that cell. This slows down the rate of charge of that cell by bleeding off current. Over several cycles this will lead to the balancing of the charge state of the cells.

The 6 pin ICs are probably comparators looking for the min and max voltages allowed and the threshold at which to turn on the balancing resistors.